# Find four-digit numbers where the first two digits squared plus the last two digits squared gives back the same number.

Tags: number-theory

If a four digit number $\overline{abcd} $ satisfies $\overline{abcd}=(\overline{ab})^2+(\overline{cd})^2$ where $a \neq 0.$ Find that number.

I think I have solved it (1233 and 8833). The way I did was kind of try and error. We have $ d \equiv b^2+d^2$ (mod 10). Then I listed all possible combinations of $b$ and $d$, and then just try and error on the value $a$ which also leads to the values of $c$. But I don't think if this is a smart/systematic method.

Comment: See [here](https://m4maths.com/10399-A-4-digit-number-abcd-satisfies-the-property-abcd-ab-2-cd-2-Find-abcd.html).

Comment: Alf van der Poorten wrote a paper about this (and generalizations, of course). I'll see if I can find it.

Comment: The Hermite-Serret Algorithm and $12^2+33^2$, in Cryptography and Computational Number Theory pp 129-136

Comment: @dietrich that would not have worked for me (I found a solution independently). It asks me to log in, so I have to register, and I assume this leads to a paywall.

Comment: Please avoid math-only titles. They are discouraged for technical reasons - see [Guidelines for good use of MathJax on question titles](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730/888233)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x$ represent the first two digits and $y$ represent the second two digits. Thus

$100x+y=x^2+y^2$

$x(100-x)=y(y-1)$

The right side is even. Modulo $5$ the left side is $\in\{0,1,2\}$ and the right side is $\in\{0,1,4\}$. Thus both sides end with $0$ or $6$. In addition the left side must be $\in\{0,1\}\bmod3$ and the right side $\in\{0,2\}\bmod3$, so both sides are multiples of $3$.

So we need $x$ to be a multiple of $3$ or one more than such, $x(100-x)$ to end in $0$ or $6$ (forcing $x$ to end in one of the digits $0,2,8$), and $4[x(100-x)]+1=(2y-1)^2$ to be a perfect square. We set out to try eligible two-digit values of $x$ from $10$ up to $50$ (nine trials), knowing that any solution for $x$ in this range will be accompanied by a solution $100-x$ by symmetry of the product $x(100-x)$ on the left side. Blocks are cases where we do not get the needed perfect square for $4[x(100-x)]+1=(2y-1)^2$:

$x=10, x(100-x)=900, 4×900+1=3601■$

$x=12, x(100-x)=1056, 4×1056+1=4225=65^2☆$

$x=18, x(100-x)=1476, 4×1476+1=5905■$

$x=22, x(100-x)=1716, 4×1716+1=6865■$

$x=28, x(100-x)=2016, 4×2016+1=8065■$

$x=30, x(100-x)=2100, 4×2100+1=8401■$

$x=40, x(100-x)=2400, 4×2400+1=9601■$

$x=42, x(100-x)=2436, 4×2436+1=9745■$

$x=48, x(100-x)=2496, 4×2496+1=9985■$

So only $x=12$ works among numbers below $50$, from which $100-x=88$ will also work among numbers above $50$, and for this pair of solutions we see $2y-1=65, y=33$. Hence

$1233=12^2+33^2$

$8833=88^2+33^2$

Answer (score 2):

I quote from Alf van der Poorten's paper. Beginquote:

Lemma 1.1. The identity $a^2+b^2=10^ua+b$ is equivalent to the representation
$10^{2u}+1=(10^u-2a)^2+(2b-1)^2$.

It's enough, therefore, to look for representations of $10^{2u}+1$ as a sum $x^2+y^2$
with $x=10^u-2a$ even, and $y=2b-1$ odd.

$$10^4+1=73\times137=(8^2+3^2)(4^2+11^2)=(8\times11-3\times4)^2+(8\times4+3\times11)^2=76^2+65^2$$

That is $a=12$ and $b=33$. Endquote.

**Watch your signs -- and sometimes both signs**

The quoted solution fails to reckon that $(10^2-2a)^2=76^2$ and $(2b-1)^2=65^2$ do not respectively imply $10^2-2a=+76, 2b-1=+65$. The right sides might equally be the negative roots instead. For the $b$ equation the negative root can be ignored because $2b-1=-65$ gives $b<0$. But we do get a second positive solution for $a$ by rendering $-76$ as the root on the equation for $a$:

$$10^2-2a=-76$$
$$a=88$$

$$b=33$$
$$\text{ from above, with the } 65 \text{ root still positive}$$

Therefore $a=88,b=33$ is a second solution.

Comment: But would not it miss another solution 8833? (And I don't know if I have missed other solution)

Comment: @gerry You also have $10^4+1=(-76)^2+65^2$. Therefore $2a=10^2-(-76)=176$ will give a second solution with a positive two-digit value for $a$, which picks up $8833$. The equivalent logic in my solution is noting that the first two digits have paired solutions adding up to $100$.

Comment: There is, of course, much more to Alf's paper than the brief segment I quoted. Applied properly, his methods get everything, and not just for four-digit examples.

Comment: @Oscar, my answer is a quote from Alf's paper, so I rolled back your edit, which added things that were not in the paper. You could edit in such a way as to make it clear that what you've added isn't Alf's, or you could just be satisfied that the full story is in the comments.

Comment: @Oscar, as I said, I'd be happy with an edit that gives the complete solution, so long as it is clearly indicated where the quote from Alf ends and the additional material begins. Of course, you are free to vote as you wish.

Comment: @Oscar, I don't know what is not clear to you. I would accept anything that clearly distinguishes what is a quote from Alf's paper, from what is not.